# asp.net core 2.1 StringValues not found

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

[image]
A simple asp.net core 2.1 mvc project, I want to  get some values from FormData,so I Use:

```
var obj = new JObject();    
foreach (var item in Request.Form)
            {
                obj[item.Key] = item.Value[0];
            }
```

these codes work fine,and I can get the item.Key and item.Value. 
Add quick watch also work fine:
[image]

But, when debug,the visual studio show tip:

```
error cs0246: cannot find StringValues
```

I google,or add reference 'Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives' by nuget,but the tip doesn't disappear.

Comment: Are you executing in debug mode?Clean your project and restore all the nuget packages

Comment: @Badulake I run in debug mode。I try. but don't work

Comment: restar visual studio and do a manual clean of all the bin/debug folders